# Как закрепить кнопку по центру снизу

Tags: html, css

Есть кнопка

```
color: #fff;
border-radius: 4px;
border: 1px solid #f6705a;
padding: 5px 20px;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Она находится в блоке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно кнопку прижать к нижней части и по центру(Контент в блоке динамичный)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавляю в css

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 25px;
right: 0;
left: 0;
text-align: center;
```

Получаю вот это

```css
.bl-i {
    height: 410px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #666666;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.view-e {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 25px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #f6705a;
    padding: 5px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bl-i">
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/0_8eb56_842bba74_XL-220x220.jpg" style="margin-top: 20px; width: 50%">
    <h5 style="margin-top: 5px;">Пруток металлический</h5>
  </div>
  <ul class="list-katalog">
    <li><span>Круг стальной</span></li>
  </ul>
  <div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 72px;">
    <a class="view-e" href="">Показать еще</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не правильно?

Comment: не используй абсолютное позиционирование для центрирования - это очень плохая практика. + из твоей задачи не ясно является ли необходимым условием фиксированная высота контейнера bl-i. Если нет - то задача элементарно решается несколькими вариантами например с помощью `display:inline-block` у кнопки + `text-align:center` у родителя. Если же у тебя всегда фиксированный контейнер в 410 пикселей то тогда нужен другой подход который учитывает возможность того что картинки будут разных размеров.

Comment: @DenisRoss почему не использовать абсолютное позиционирование? Блок с фиксированной высотой и с динамическим контентом, то есть у картинки может быть разный размер и сами пункты(+-)

Comment: Если блок фиксированной высоты  то это в какой-то мере меняет дело - можно и абсолютом ее прилепить к низу конечно, но я бы поступил иначе. Ты ведь хочешь чтобы все выглядело красиво и идентично для разных картинок (имеется ввиду размер) или что бы в случае маленькой картинки кнопка уже была не прилеплена к низу а шла сразу за картинкой? И если картинка очень большая и не влезает в 410px ее по хорошему тоже оставлять в таком виде нельзя. Опиши подробнее поведение всего блока в целом - я сверстаю, там ничего сложного.

Comment: При использовании маленькой картинки, кнопка все равно должна находиться в нижней части, при использовании большой картинки ей задается(max-height) чтобы она далеко не лезла(Примерно до h5), li минимальное количество 1, максимальное количество 5 штук

Comment: А блок `ul` прилеплен к кнопке (в случае маленькой картинки остается снизу вместе с кнопкой) ? или же прилеплен к картинке?

Comment: Прикреплен к картинке

Comment: ок, последний момент - могут ли в `ul li` быть длинные надписи которые не помещаются на одной строке? Если да - то каково поведение? (перенос на след строку и считать что их общее кол-во увеличилось на одну)? Ширина исходного контейнера статическая или динамическая? Исходный контейнер будет наверняка инлайновым и их будет несколько в ряд, я правильно понимаю? Хорошо бы знать максимальный и минимальный размеры тогда. Картинка должна растягиваться по ширине блока или всегда быть 50% от его ширины? Я бы вообще в таком варианте сделал картинку background-image если честно.

Comment: Пропустил с ul li, они могут быть длинными с перемещением на следующую строку, да считать, максимальное ко-во строк(ul li) 5 штук, то есть под li рассчитано всего 5 строчек. Ширина динамичная(При уменьшении экрана не много играет) максимальная 255, минимальная 210px. Их от 2-х до 4-х в ряд. Картинка по все ширине блока, просто в примере не влазило 100% я немного уменьшил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я все правильно понял, то у тебя должно быть что-то вроде этого. Но тут кончено нужно осторожно играться с размерами шрифта ul-li, чтобы они не вылазили за пределы.

```css
.block {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  height: 410px;
  width: 255px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #666666;
}

.image img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.description ul {
  margin: 0;
}

.more {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.more a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #f6705a;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">

  <div class="block">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/0_8eb56_842bba74_XL-220x220.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      <ul>
        <li>Первая строка</li>
        <li>Вторая строка</li>
        <li>Третья строка</li>
        <li>Четвертая строка</li>
        <li>Пятая строка</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="more">
      <a href="#">Показать еще</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/0_8eb56_842bba74_XL-220x220.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      <ul>
        <li>Первая строка</li>
        <li>Вторая строка</li>
        <li>Третья строка - очень длинная строка вы вмещающаяся в заданныую ширину</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="more">
      <a href="#">Показать еще</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://www.google.ru/doodle4google/images/splashes/featured.png">
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      <ul>
        <li>Одна строка</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="more">
      <a href="#">Показать еще</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает, а немного рассказать, как влияет `.block{position: relative` на `.more{position: absolute` то есть зачем для .block задается позиция?

Comment: а тут вот какой прикол - если ты не задашь родительскому контейнер позиционирование, то есть в данном случае block оставишь без указания relative, то для его дочернего элемента .more с позиционирование absolute все вычисления будут вестись от того блока которому позиционирование явно задано или он самого верхнего родителя (в данном случае это .example). Попробуй убрать у block `position:relative` и у тебя все сразу съедет, потому что .more будет уже свой bottom:0 считать не от block, а от example.

Comment: все понял, пожалуй займусь более глубоким изучением этого позиционирования

Comment: помимо позиционирования попробуй поискать в целом информацию про так называемый "контекст" элемента. С ним много подводных камней связано. Вот только внятного материала я откровенно на русском и не видел, но может плохо искал.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.bl-i {
    height: 410px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #666666;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.view-e {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 25px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -67px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #f6705a;
    padding: 5px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bl-i">
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/0_8eb56_842bba74_XL-220x220.jpg" style="margin-top: 20px; width: 50%">
    <h5 style="margin-top: 5px;">Пруток металлический</h5>
  </div>
  <ul class="list-katalog">
    <li><span>Круг стальной</span></li>
  </ul>
  <div style="margin-top: 72px;">
    <a class="view-e" href="">Показать еще</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Попробуйте так, если верно понял вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо, работает